# JAXBElement<T> is not getting generated in my case when using wsimport to generate java classes

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am using wsimport of jaxws-maven plugin version 1.12 to generate java classes from WSDL which has an XSD imported in it.

I have the element like this

```
<xs:complexType name="NameType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="somename" type="xs:SomeType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I need `LIst<JAXBElement<SomeType>>` but its is coming like `List<SomeType>`

I have gone through some of the links but found hte reverse way of doing this like eliminating the creation of `JAXBElement` by using `generateElementproperty=false` in bindings.

I tried having `generateElementproperty=true` to that particular element but its not working.

When i use this property in XSD its working but i can't change the xsd as it is provided by vendor.

I want to know how can i do this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you need `JAXBElement<SomeType>`?

Comment: It is possible to extend [JAXB2 Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin) to convert `@XmlElement` property to `@XmlElementRef` property. Please file an issue if you want this.

Comment: i need JAXBElement<T> because i need to setNil(true) using it.